# React findDOMNode alternative for text nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to create a text editor such as Draft.js, which entails using contentEditable. Anyways, I'm using MutationObserver to detect changes and I want to be able to reflect changes to the DOM in the state.

> When a component renders to a string, findDOMNode returns a text DOM node containing that value.

I want to compare the mutation target to the rendered dom and reflect those changes in the app state. It would most likely work if I used findDOMNode, however it's deprecated. Is there an alternative? Or, is there a way to use refs to make this happen?

As an example, I have a PElement class:

```
class PElement extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            children = []
        }
        /*Parse content props, etc, for children*/
        this.ref = React.createRef();
        this.compare = this.compare.bind(this);
    }
    compare (node) {
        //This will allow me to check if the target of the mutation was this component.
        return this.ref.current === node;
    }
    render () {
        return (<p ref={this.ref}>{this.state.children}</p>);
    }
}
```

As for the Text class:

```
class Text extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        //No state. This will be lowest level and controlled.
        this.ref = React.createRef();
        this.compare = this.compare.bind(this);
    }
    compare (node) {
        return this.ref.current === node;
    }
    render () {
        //I don't know how to create a ref to the rendered text node.
        return this.props.content;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a Text node and use React.cloneElement, though it didn't work.

In the end, I settled on inferring the location of the Text component by mutating the state with each mutation, ie childList by adding or removing components and checking the child nodes of the parent. This way I can know which Component renders which node.

Though, on second thought, I might just prevent input and modify the state in the way which it should be, based on the captured input. It's more in line with the philosophy of React.